# How can I include a perl command in sed?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, sed, tcsh

I have log files I need to cut, which output DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS on every line. Ideally I would like the last 10 minutes of such a file.

I have a perl command to get the time 10 minutes ago:

```
perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%e-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",\ localtime(time()- 600);'
```

Sample output: 29-02-2012 16:38:14

and a sed command to cut the file. This works with a manual date and the system time now as the second variable. I cannot use date's more advanced features as I am using Solaris 8 I think and the c shell.

```
sed '1,/29-02-2012 16:07/d;/=$(date +%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")/,$d' debug.log | tee cut-log | less
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: you can manipulate Solaris 8 date with TZ var (don't have access to that stuff right now), a google groups search in comp.unix.shell will bring that up. See if your system has GNU tools installed, often in /usr/local/bin, which would make things easier. Also, while not a great shell, there's nothing about what you're doing that shouldn't be possible in csh. All that said, I think kev below is on the right track. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the whole thing in perl, use the `..` operator.  Something like

```
perl -MPOSIX -n -e 'print if /@{[ strftime "%e-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",\ localtime(time()- 600) ]}/ .. /@{[ strftime "%e-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",\ localtime(time()) ]}/ '
```

Edit: bad paste of the code.  I've fixed it.

Comment: Forgive me as I'm new but I got this error:

    >perl -MPOSIX -n -e 'print if /${[ strftime "%e-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",\ localtime(time()- 600) ]}/ .. /${[ strftime "%e-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",\ localtime(time() ]}/ '
syntax error at -e line 1, near ") ]"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Do I pass this to sed after?

Answer (score 1):

`$(date)` doesn't expand in single quoted string. Change to double quote.

```
sed "1,/29-02-2012 16:07/d;/=$(date +'%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')/,\$d"
```